# PR2: client not rights to move the robot

Tags: ros-groovy, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Commands from the robot to the robot are working, but command from the computer to the robot are not.
Take for example the following command to move the head.

```
  rostopic pub -1 /head_traj_controller/command trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory '{joint_names: ["head_pan_joint", "head_tilt_joint"], points: [ { positions: [0,0], velocities: [0,0], time_from_start: [2,0] } ]}'
rostopic pub -1 /head_traj_controller/command trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory '{joint_names: ["head_pan_joint", "head_tilt_joint"], points: [ { positions: [1,0], velocities: [0,0], time_from_start: [2,0] } ]}'
```

When I run this command on the robot (connected through ssh), the head of the robot moves. But when I do it with my computer, it doesn't work. I can see and read all the topics though from my computer. I need to be able to control the robot from my computer in order to use for example rviz.

Any thoughts ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154766/pr2:-client-not-rights-to-move-the-robot/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect this is a network/DNS problem.

You should be able to reproduce it by running the example talker on your computer and the listener on the robot.

I suspect the issue here is that the robot can't resolve the hostname of your computer. To verify, start up the listener on the robot and the talker on your computer, and then try to `rosnode ping` the talker from the robot. If it fails, you probably have a network problem. You can then run `rosnode info` on the talker to see which hostname it's using, and either fix the DNS entries for that hostname, add it to the /etc/hosts file on the robot, or set `ROS_IP` on your computer before starting the talker.

For more background, watch my [Networking for ROS Users](https://vimeo.com/67806888) talk from ROSCON 2013

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-04-18**:
You're my hero dude (in fact when I was asking the question though you were going to answer)! In the lab there is no dns resolve for each computer, we got it only for the robot. Therefore, as you said, I set the ROS_IP variable and it works. And pretty nice explanation in your video. Thanks!